# Multicast in Rackspace cloud

Tags: cloud-computing, rackspace, multicast

On Amazon EC2, I cannot use multicast, but how about rackspace cloud? It would be very beneficial to be able to use multicast as most clustering protocols rely on it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multicast isn't currently allowed on Rackspace Cloud Servers.  The traffic volume of multicast traffic ends up overloading the switching layer and it degrades network performance for all traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I heard it was a way to have multicast with openVPN... using TAP instead of TUN.

So it could works on both ec2 and rackspace, and you ensure that just your clients are allowed to subscribe to multicast group because only your clients are allowed to use your openVPN.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use multicast on the Rackspace cloud network, how would you ensure that only your clients were permitted to subscribe to the multicast group ?

Comment: I would probably leave that for the Rackspace folks to worry about ;)

Comment: Seems like a solution like Amazon VPC would be ideal for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multicast with Rackspace Cloud Networks, it is a full Layer 2 networking virtual network.

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/networks/

Here is an example on how to set it up for MYSQL replication
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-replication-masterslave

Comment: MySQL replication is actually unicast, TCP... not multicast.